# Best way to count for each type in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wonder what is the best way to convert the following source data set to target data set: 
Source data set:

```
ID | Type | Count
111|  A   | 1
111|  B   | 2
111|  C   | 1
222|  A   | 3
333|  C   | 2
```

Target data set:

```
ID  |#ofTypeA | #ofTypeB | #ofTypeC
111 |   1     |    2     |    1
222 |   3     |    0     |    0
333 |   0     |    0     |    2
```

The source data set was created from a raw data set using GroupBy(ID, Type).count() 
Right now the only way I can think of is join the raw data-set with the source data set multiple times, each time create a new column for counting of each type.
But it will resolved in 3 joins.
I wonder if there is any an better way to do it

The raw data set is like this:

```
ID | Type
111| A
111| B
111| B
.......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot` to with `groupby` to get the result you want

```
  val df = Seq(
    (111, "A", 1),
    (111, "B", 2),
    (111, "C", 1),
    (222, "A", 3),
    (333, "C", 2)
  ).toDF("Id", "Type", "Count")

  df.groupBy("Id")
    .pivot("Type")
    .agg(sum($"Count"))
    .na.fill(0)
    .show(false)
```

You can use `na.fill(0)` to replace the `null` with `0`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! learning new thing

Comment: Great, glad that helped